# RStudio shiny to shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here is my code for R shiny (only UI part):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(wordcloud2)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Title of App",
  tabPanel("Category 1",icon = icon("search"), 
       fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"), 

         headerPanel("header for title 1"),
         titlePanel(h3("title for category 1")),

         wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}'),
                   id = "leftPanel",
                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb1=='1'",
                                    textInput("sc_number", h5("Enter a Number:"), 10)
                   ),
                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb1=='2'",
                                    textInput("string_1", h5("Enter String:"), "string here")
                   ),
                   br(),
                   selectInput("group_text_1", "Select Groups",
                               choices = c("gr1","gr2","gr3"),
                               selected = "gr1",
                               multiple = TRUE),
                   br(),
                   actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_1", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
         ),
         mainPanel(                          
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel(value="1", "Tab #1", hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_number")),
             tabPanel(value="2", "Tab #2" , hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_date")),
             id = "tb1")
         )
       )
  ),
  tabPanel("Category 2",icon = icon("search-plus"), 
       fluidPage(

         headerPanel("header 2"),
         titlePanel(h2("title 2")),

         wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}'),
                   id = "leftPanel",
                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb2=='1'",
                                    textInput("string_2", h5("Enter String:"), "able to update string")
                   ),
                   br(),
                   checkboxGroupInput('swords', 'Select words:', 
                                      c("pain","massage","physio",
                                        "family","angry","upset","stress","complain"),
                                      selected = c("pain","massage")),
                   br(),
                   actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_2", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
         ),

         mainPanel(                          
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel(value="1","Tab #1", 
                      helpText("data:"), hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("se_doc")
             ),
             tabPanel("Tab #2", 
                      wordcloud2Output("se_search_cloud",width = "100%")
             ),
             id = "tb2")
         )
       )
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My main question is how can I convert this code to shinydashboard. Particularly how conditionalPanel works in shinydashboard.

I believe my code is not efficient; particularly for the following issues:

1. I have "Select words" and I like to have them similar to "Select Groups" but with checkbox. Using selectInput with multiple=TRUe does not show checkbox.
2. I also used similar variables such as "string_1 and string_2" and "GoButton_1 and GoButton_2", but they are for the same purpose. Can I name both with one variable such as  "string" and "GoButton"?

Here is a screenshot from my shiny.

[image]

I appreciate your updates and comments to improve the code.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this and let me know what you think

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(wordcloud2)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title of App"), 
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                  menuItem(text = "Category 1",tabName = "Category_1",icon = icon("search")),
                                  menuItem(text = "Category 2",tabName = "Category_2",icon = icon("search-plus"))
                      )
                    ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Category_1",
               fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"), 

                         headerPanel("header for title 1"),
                         titlePanel(h3("title for category 1")),

                         wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}'),
                                   id = "leftPanel",
                                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb1=='1'",
                                                    textInput("sc_number", h5("Enter a Number:"), 10)
                                   ),
                                   conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb1=='2'",
                                                    textInput("string_1", h5("Enter String:"), "string here")
                                   ),
                                   br(),
                                   selectInput("group_text_1", "Select Groups",
                                               choices = c("gr1","gr2","gr3"),
                                               selected = "gr1",
                                               multiple = TRUE),
                                   br(),
                                   actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_1", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                         ),
                         mainPanel(                          
                           tabsetPanel(
                             tabPanel(value="1", "Tab #1", hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_number")),
                             tabPanel(value="2", "Tab #2" , hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_date")),
                             id = "tb1")
                         )
               )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Category_2",
               fluidPage(

                 headerPanel("header 2"),
                 titlePanel(h2("title 2")),

                 wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}'),
                           id = "leftPanel",
                           conditionalPanel(condition="input.tb2=='1'",
                                            textInput("string_2", h5("Enter String:"), "able to update string")
                           ),
                           br(),
                           checkboxGroupInput('swords', 'Select words:', 
                                              c("pain","massage","physio",
                                                "family","angry","upset","stress","complain"),
                                              selected = c("pain","massage")),
                           br(),
                           actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_2", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                 ),

                 mainPanel(                          
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel(value="1","Tab #1", 
                              helpText("data:"), hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("se_doc")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab #2", 
                              wordcloud2Output("se_search_cloud",width = "100%")
                     ),
                     id = "tb2")
                 )
               )
      )  
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update:**

*Based on further comments.*

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(wordcloud2)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title of App", 
                    tags$li(
                      class = "dropdown",
                      tags$a(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                        menuItem(text = "Category 1",tabName = "Category_1",icon = icon("search")),
                        menuItem(text = "Category 2",tabName = "Category_2",icon = icon("search-plus"))),
                        style = "padding-top: 0px;
                                 padding-right: 0px;
                                 padding-bottom: 0px;
                                 padding-left: 0px;"
                      ))
                    ),
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                        div(id = "leftPanel_1", fluidPage(
                                          textInput("sc_number", h5("Enter a Number:"), 10)
                                          ,
                                          hidden(textInput("string_1", h5("Enter String:"), "string here")
                                          ),
                                          br(),
                                          selectInput("group_text_1", "Select Groups",
                                                      choices = c("gr1","gr2","gr3"),
                                                      selected = "gr1",
                                                      multiple = TRUE),
                                          br(),
                                          actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_1", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                        )),
                        hidden(div(id = "leftPanel_2", fluidPage(
                                          textInput("string_2", h5("Enter String:"), "able to update string")
                                          ,
                                          br(),
                                          checkboxGroupInput('swords', 'Select words:', 
                                                             c("pain","massage","physio",
                                                               "family","angry","upset","stress","complain"),
                                                             selected = c("pain","massage")),
                                          br(),
                                          actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_2", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                        )))
                    ),
                    body = dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "Category_1",
                                fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"), 

                                          headerPanel("header for title 1"),
                                          titlePanel(h3("title for category 1")),

                                          mainPanel(                          
                                            tabsetPanel(
                                              tabPanel(value="1", "Tab #1", hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_number")),
                                              tabPanel(value="2", "Tab #2" , hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_date")),
                                              id = "tb1")
                                          )
                                )
                        ),
                        tabItem(tabName = "Category_2",
                                fluidPage(

                                  headerPanel("header 2"),
                                  titlePanel(h2("title 2")),

                                  mainPanel(                          
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                      tabPanel(value="1","Tab #1", 
                                               helpText("data:"), hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("se_doc")
                                      ),
                                      tabPanel("Tab #2", 
                                               wordcloud2Output("se_search_cloud",width = "100%")
                                      ),
                                      id = "tb2")
                                  )
                                )
                        )  
                      ),
                      useShinyjs()
                    ),
                    tagList(
                      tags$head(
                        tags$style(
                                   ".main-header .navbar-custom-menu {
                                        float: left;
                                      }
                                   .sidebar-menu {
                                        display: flex;
                                   }"
                        )
                      )
                    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    toggle('leftPanel_1')
    toggle('leftPanel_2')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$tb1, {
    toggle('sc_number')
    toggle('string_1')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$tb2, {
    toggle('string_2')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Further Update:**

*Dealing with additional questions 1 and 2.*

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(wordcloud2)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title of App", 
                    tags$li(
                      class = "dropdown",
                      tags$a(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                        menuItem(text = "Category 1",tabName = "Category_1",icon = icon("search")),
                        menuItem(text = "Category 2",tabName = "Category_2",icon = icon("search-plus"))),
                        style = "padding-top: 0px;
                                 padding-right: 0px;
                                 padding-bottom: 0px;
                                 padding-left: 0px;"
                      ))
                    ),
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                        div(id = "leftPanel_1", fluidPage(
                                          textInput("sc_number", h5("Enter a Number:"), 10)
                                          ,
                                          hidden(textInput("string_1", h5("Enter String:"), "string here")
                                          ),
                                          br(),
                                          selectInput("group_text_1", "Select Groups",
                                                      choices = c("gr1","gr2","gr3"),
                                                      selected = "gr1",
                                                      multiple = TRUE),
                                          br(),
                                          actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_1", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                        )),
                        hidden(div(id = "leftPanel_2", fluidPage(
                                          textInput("string_2", h5("Enter String:"), "able to update string")
                                          ,
                                          br(),
                                          pickerInput('swords', 'Select words:', 
                                                             c("pain","massage","physio",
                                                               "family","angry","upset","stress","complain"),
                                                             selected = c("pain","massage"), multiple = TRUE,
                                                             options = list(
                                                               `actions-box` = TRUE)),
                                          br(),
                                          actionButton(inputId = "GoButton_2", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                        )))
                    ),
                    body = dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "Category_1",
                                fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"), 

                                          headerPanel("header for title 1"),
                                          titlePanel(h3("title for category 1")),

                                          mainPanel(                          
                                            tabsetPanel(
                                              tabPanel(value="1", "Tab #1", hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_number")),
                                              tabPanel(value="2", "Tab #2" , hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("sc_table_date")),
                                              id = "tb1")
                                          )
                                )
                        ),
                        tabItem(tabName = "Category_2",
                                fluidPage(

                                  headerPanel("header 2"),
                                  titlePanel(h2("title 2")),

                                  mainPanel(                          
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                      tabPanel(value="1","Tab #1", 
                                               helpText("data:"), hr(), DT::dataTableOutput("se_doc")
                                      ),
                                      tabPanel("Tab #2", 
                                               wordcloud2Output("se_search_cloud",width = "100%")
                                      ),
                                      id = "tb2")
                                  )
                                )
                        )  
                      ),
                      useShinyjs()
                    ),
                    tagList(
                      tags$head(
                        tags$style(
                                   ".main-header .navbar-custom-menu {
                                        float: left;
                                      }
                                   .sidebar-menu {
                                        display: flex;
                                   }"
                        )
                      )
                    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
    toggle('leftPanel_1')
    toggle('leftPanel_2')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$tb1, {
    toggle('sc_number')
    toggle('string_1')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$tb2, {
    toggle('string_2')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above adds a pickerInput from the shinyWidgets package that allows for check marks alongside choices. I have further added the select all/deselect all options.

Below is a way of adding one GoButton after the other sidebar items. However you did not specify the accompanying functionality so I am not sure that this is useful as each "GoButton" presumably does different things. So too with the textInputs. It may be better to separate them from the start. The "string" textInputs are also trickier as they need to be displayed under different conditions.

```
fluidPage(
                          br(),
                          actionButton(inputId = "GoButton", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
                        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Eli for your answer, is it possible to take categories to the header (in front of "Title of App") and sidebar panels to the left when you click on categories, exactly similar to my screenshot. Also do you have any comments or my other questions (1 & 2)?

Comment: Glad to help, Sam. Unfortunately I won't be able to look at much until next week Wednesday. Take a look at this link for your question 1 - https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets#select-picker

Comment: Thanks Eli for the link.

Comment: Hi Eli, do you have any updates for my question? I would like to have category 1 and category 2 in front of header (or in sidebar). But when one clicks on each of them, one can see inputs related to them in the sidebar. In your code, inputs are in dashboardbody.

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry for the delayed response. Please see updated answer above...and further updated answer. Please install packages shinyjs and shinyWidgets if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Eli for your great update. All Ok now. Only one small thing: how can I have "category 2" in front of "category 1"? If I have more categories, it is better to have them in one row, in front of each other, to have more space for the body.

Comment: Hi Sam. I don't quite understand. They are currently in the same row. Do you want them in the same column in the header i.e. category 2 below category 1?

Comment: If that's what you mean then just remove
.sidebar-menu {
                                        display: flex;
                                   }

Comment: Hi Eli, In my computer they are in the same column, i.e. "category 2" under "category 1". I want to have them in the same row, like category 1  space category 2. I removed .sidebar-menu { display: flex; }  but it does not affect. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, okay I understand now. That is strange because that {display: flex} puts them in the same row for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tested on Chrome and Internet Explorer with the same results. Has .main-header .navbar-custom-menu {
                                        float: left;
                                      } 
sent the categories to the left of the header or are they in the top right corner?

Comment: You can try replace flex with -webkit-box, -webkit-inline-box or inline-flex which all put the categories inline for me. Keep me posted.

Comment: Hi Eli, Thanks so much. -webkit-box and -webkit-inline-box worked for me. flex and inline-flex give me categories in the same column. I am using Chrome, does it affect the results?

Comment: I am using Chrome too so that's weird. It must be the version or some system settings. Anyway, glad it's working!

Comment: Hi Eli, Thank you so much for your kind reply and a great answer.

Comment: Sure, glad to have helped out.